# How to copy one table from database1 to database2 using sql?My codes result finally lost primary key

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I use the sql like this,finally I can copy the table struct and data from table1,but I find table2 do not have primary key,and my table1 actually have a primary key called id which automatically adds 1 each time.

```
select *  into database2.table2 from  database1.table1
```

Comment: if you want to keep the data consistent between databases/tables, its a better practice to disable constraints on the target, and re-instate them once the work is done

Answer (score 0):

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT tablename ON /* on destination table */


INSERT INTO database2.table2 ( ColA, ColB, ColC) select ColA, ColB, ColC database1.table1


SET IDENTITY_INSERT tablename OFF /* on destination table */
```

Comment: This way just insert the data in a exist table  called table2.Now I wonder how to insert the data in a non-existent table and set its primary key automatically adds 1 each time.

Answer (score 0):

```
select *  into database2.table2 from  database1.table1
alter table table2 alter column id int identity(1,1)  not null 
alter table table2  add constraint pkid primary key (id)
```